# How to spawn concurrent computation in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, concurrency, clojure, stm

If I've got a function which does four very long computation and return a list with the result of the four computation, but where each computation doesn't depend on another, how do you "parallelize" this in Haskell?

To better explain my question, here's a Clojure example of what I have in mind:

```
(defn some-function [arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4]
  let [c1 (very-long-computation arg1)
       c2 (very-long-computation arg2)
       c3 (very-long-computation arg3)
       c4 (very-long-computation arg4)]
    [c1 c2 c3 c4])
```

You could spawn three additional threads doing, say:

```
(defn some-function [arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4]
  let [c1 (future (very-long-computation arg1))
       c2 (future (very-long-computation arg2))
       c3 (future (very-long-computation arg3))
       c4 (very-long-computation arg4)] ; no need to wrap c4 in a future
    [@c1 @c2 @c3 c4])
```

Would something like what follows in Haskell be equivalent?

```
someFunction :: (a -> a -> a ->a) -> [a]
  do c1 <- rpar (very-long-computation arg1)
     c2 <- rpar (very-long-computation arg2)
     c3 <- rpar (very-long-computation arg3)
     c4 <- (very-long-computation arg4)
     rseq c1
     rseq c2
     rseq c3
     return (c1, c2, c3, c4)
```

Do I need to rpar/rseq c4?

Is rpar/rseq the way to go for such concurrent computation?

What if I don't rseq, will the program wait, later on, when I try to access the return values inside the list that is returned?

Is this transparent or do you need to do something like the "deref" that takes place in Clojure when you use '@'?

Comment: Check out Simon Marlow's awesome [new book](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/index.html)

Answer (score 4):

You're most likely looking for the [`async`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.0.1.4/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html) package. For example, if you'd like to race the three computations and take the one that finishes first:

```
someFunction :: IO a
someFunction = do
    c1 <- async $ veryLongComputation1
    c2 <- async $ veryLongComputation2
    c3 <- async $ veryLongComputation3
    (_, a) <- waitAny $ [c1, c2, c3]
    return a
```

Or you can use `wait` on particular `async` threads, and share state via `stm`. It's a very useful package for this sort of thing. The precise version you asked for in the OP would look something like:

```
someFunction :: IO (a, b, c, d)
someFunction = do
    c1 <- async $ veryLongComputation1
    c2 <- async $ veryLongComputation2
    c3 <- async $ veryLongComputation3
    v4 <- veryLongComputation4
    -- wait for all the results and return them as a tuple
    wait $ (,,,) <$> c1 <*> c2 <*> c3 <*> (return v4)
```

This of course assumes that `c1, c2, c3` are all side-effecting and you're not interested in the results. `wait` and `poll` get you the values.

I also highly recommend the book "Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell" by Simon Marlow.

Comment: +1 but... There's no side-effect, the [@c1,@c2,@c3,c4] in the Clojure example is actually the return value. The function won't return until it has "deref'ed" c1, c2 and c3 (that is: until they're done).

Comment: Yep, in Haskell forking and inspecting the future for its value are two separate operations. Until you do, you've only got an `Async a` and not an `a`. This is so that you can control when you decide to pause and `wait` on a thread and when you simply `poll` to see if its finished.

Comment: @CedricMartin: I edited the answer with the semantics you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend [MonadPar](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-par-0.3.4.6). I have used Strategies before, but you still have to know "magic" commands to get everything to evaluate in parallel. In my experience, MonadPar just works.

Here's a simple example:

```
import Control.Monad.Par
import Control.Monad

foo :: [a] -> a
foo [x] = x
foo xs = 
   let len = length xs
       x1 = take len xs
       x2 = drop len xs
   in runPar $ do
     p1 <- spawnP $ foo x1
     p2 <- spawnP $ foo x2
     liftM2 (*) (get p1) $ get p2
```

Of course, this does require *sufficient parallelism* to actually be beneficial. In my experience, the parallelism overhead is quite high in Haskell.

Comment: ah, it's interesting to read that it's quite high in Haskell. In Clojure for something as "simple" as two "BigInt" multiplication / modulo you can already save a few ms by simply spawning a "future". I guess I'll have to run some tests to get an idea as to when it starts to make sense to use parallelism in Haskell! My question anyway was to get the "big picture" as to how parallelism works in Haskell, +1 and thanks a lot.

Comment: You never know: that could just be a reflection of the slowness of Clojure in computing BigInts rather than the low overhead of its threads!